# System preferences crashes when press accounts

Tags: system-settings

I'm trying to help someone else with their computer, every time I try to access the "Accounts" settings in system preferences, system preferences hangs and then crashes, any idea what's up? The computer is a Macbook 2.4Gz Core Duo, and all the software is up to date.

-Thanks

**Edit**: This is what comes up in console.

```
2/18/11 9:25:24 PM  System Preferences[201] NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:: nil value
2/18/11 9:25:24 PM  System Preferences[201] NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:: nil value
2/18/11 9:26:37 PM  System Preferences[201] [NSPrefPaneBundle instantiatePrefPaneObject] (/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Accounts.prefPane): should only be called once
```

Comment: Can you open Console (`/Applications/Utilities/Console` and post what you see there for System Preferences)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get better answers if you provide more information such as when this started happening.  For example, did you add a new account recently?  Install any applications recently?

Normally, when weird stuff happens on OS X such as crashes, repairing permissions can be a good place to start.  Try opening Disk Utility and select your computers Hard Drive on the left hand side, then click 'Repair Permissions'.  This will take a few minutes and may solve your problem.  Try a restart after the repair before you go back into Accounts.

Have you tried this under a different user account?  I've come across instances of people having this only occur on one account.  You could create a new account and restore documents etc from a backup.

Comment: Tried repairing permissions, didn't help.

Comment: No problem @Ben, if I can think of anything else which might help I'll update the answer.  Some people just down-vote because they can.

Answer (score 0):

It may causes due to corrupt .plist file. Try removing SystemPreference plist file from ~/Library/Preferences/SystemPreference.plist(Close the Sys Pref before doing this). A new file will be created when you start System Preferences again.

Answer (score 0):

Are users authenticating with a Directory Server like OpenLDAP or Active Directory? Also, what version of OS X is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

As suggested [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23596820#23596820), I removed the folder `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.iCloudHelper` and that fixed it.